# Search for string and multiply

Tags: vba, excel

I have a consolidated worksheet with all of my part quantities listed. In column B are my quantity values. I need to be able to search for this phrase: `Qty. typical for #` in column A and then multiply all quantity values in column B until B is blank.

I can search and find the phrase, but I'm at a standstill as to how to manipulate the data in VBA to do precisely what I want:

Search for "Qty. typical for #"

Take #(A) and multiply by Qty.(B)

Do Until IsEmpty

Edit:

[Data Pull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0RIU.png)

Sorry, I wrote in a hurry.

I want to replace the values with the updated quantity. The consolidated file can have up to 5000 lines, which is why I am looking for something in vba. This is just a small part of a bunch of macros I put together for the engineers.

Obviously, I am not good at coding. I'm trying to learn, but my job comes first. This is just something I've been messing with on my free time, but it is very much script kiddie amateur hour on my part.

Thanks for the help so far, but the formula isn't exactly working for me either.

Comment: A image of your data and desired output would be great.  Just load something into imugr and post the link in your original post.  As your question stands it is very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Edited per pnuts' and Eem's suggestion and after OP's clarification.

In column C just do `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("for",A1,1)-3)*B1` and drag formula down. Works for any number of digits.

[image]

If you need VBA, just drop the formula via a loop?

Comment: why the assumption that the number is just one digit?

Comment: @pnuts The way OP phrased it, `#` is last char?

Comment: I have a consolidated worksheet that combines many sheets into one. In this particular step, the engineers write "Qty. typical for 3" if the exact same quantity of parts are used for three separate units. In order to get a correct count, I need to program a way to take the phrase and multiply the amount mentioned to the quantities listed.

Comment: Is it always one digit? If not, easier with`instr` in VBA.

Comment: It can be between 2 and 200.

Comment: Well, when OP says `engineers write "Qty. typical for 3"`, isn't it somewhat of a fantasy to add `Kubota fork` inside the quotes? I know it's just your years of coding speaking ^_^ Perhaps you're one of those that press 5 on an elevator when you mean 6 ^_^;